# Remote cross-platform project in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, raspberry-pi, cross-platform, orange-pi

I would like to make a C/C++ app for OrangePi zero. As orpi zero is a pretty low power running Eclipse on it is pain.

I would prefer to run Eclipse on Windows machine and remotely build and run/debug the app on orpi. I tried to achieve this by using RSE. After setting up RSE connection I can make a remote project. Edit files but without auto-completion, showing declarations(missing headers) and so on. Also, I cannot compile or run the app.

Is there any other way than cross-compiling on Windows and deploying to remote orpi? Some way to have autocompletion and compiling directly using orpi toolchain? Or at least have auto-completion working. My biggest concern about using cross-compile toolchain is dependency hell for external libraries.

Orpi is running Armbian. Developing in Eclipse 4.9

Comment: Sorry, the term "cross-compiling" describes exactly what you want to do. alternatively, could you use eclipse from windows just to edit the files on the RP, and actually build from a command-line using makefiles on the RP? You can probably remote-debug from eclipse as well. You could easily have a windows-local copy of the RP library header files that eclipse can use. I do something similar for unix development with a powerful but graphically poor linux server. Note that you will waste some time getting the eclipse error hilighter down to an acceptable level.

Comment: Not really, I would like to do it like Netbeans remote build host way. Netbeans will search for remote toolchain and so on. After providing connection info everything is set up automatically. Auto-completion, remote compiling, functions declarations working out of box. Is something like this possible in Eclipse?